# Mixing Least squares and Kalman fitler

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-calculus, least-squares, estimation, kalman-filter

I'm not sure it is the right department. I try my chance

I am wondering if there is a way to make a hybrid formulation of a least-square problem and a Kalman filter. Let me explain what I mean:

The (linear) least-square formulation reads for a set of observation $y \in \mathbb{R}^{q}$

$$\hat x = \min_x {\epsilon^\top \epsilon}\quad \text{subject to} \quad y = C x + L \epsilon$$

with $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^q$ , $C \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times n}$, $L \in \mathbb R^{q\times q}$ (weighting matrix) and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the state to be estimated.

Kalman filter makes use of a dynamical model for the state and a linear mapping from the observation to the state

\begin{align}
 x_k & = A_k x_{k-1} + B_k u_{k} + w_k \\
 y_k & = C_k x_k + v_k
\end{align}

Where $w_k$ and $v_k$ (plant and measurement noise) account for uncertainty in the model. $u_k \in \mathbb{R}^p$ some known imput.

Although I understand good both least-squares and Kalman filters I was wondering how to build a hybrid formulation of the both. I've been asked to create a model for **a part only** of the state (call it $\tilde x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $m < n$). I now managed to find a linear model that I'm happy with.

To include my model I perform a Kalman filter on $\tilde x$ and then on the rest of the state $x \backslash \tilde x \in \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ (not the best notation sorry) I perform the least-square problem (already developed by someone else). It doesn't seem to give me good results though... I also tried to use the estimate of the filter as an observation entering the least-squares (the result is better, still less good than simple least-square without KF).

Is there a way to formulate the whole thing only as a least-square problem? I'm imagining something like using the prediction part of the Kalman filter algorithm

$$\tilde x_{k/ k-1} = A_k \tilde x_{k-1/ k-1} + B_k u_k$$

and then include the update step somehow directly in the least-squares.

$$\tilde x_{k/ k} = \tilde x_{k/ k-1} + K_k (\tilde y - C_k \tilde x_{k/ k-1})$$

I think it should be possible because it also uses the information of the observations $y$. Otherwise any other ideas would be most welcome!

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not completely sure I understand what you mean. Could try to give a more precise problem formulation what you are trying to solve? Are you only using the information of one measurement or multiple when doing least squares? And would recursive least squares maybe be something you could use?

Comment: A kalman filter *is* minimizing a squared error term, though, so it *is* a least-squares method.

Comment: Kwin van der Veen. The whole thing is a bit tricky. We are already solving recursive least-squares (it is a combination of RLS and using the results to solve a PDE which results is again used to solve RLS etc. until convergence). 
However, it is a static process. As I managed to find a model (on a part of the state) I've been asked to use it to improve the results. I imediately thought of Kalman filters. However as it is just part of the state I need to keep the RLS. So how to combine it? :)

Comment: @user3716267 yes I know and it is the whole motivation behind my question!